# Formik OnSubmit Not Getting Triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am working on a react project and i am using Formik for forms. For some reason, the onSubmit method doesnt get triggered. I have been trying to figure out where the error is but i have couldnt.

I have an almost similar setup on another component and that works fine. Any help is appreciated.

There are no issues with validation, because the button becomes enabled only if it satisfies the validation parameters. I click the submit button and nothing happens. I have tried debugging but its not even hitting the onSubmit method.

```
<Segment>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            comments: "",
            mk1: "",
            mk2: "",
            mk3: "",
            mk4: "",
            mk1Num: 0,
            mk2Num: 0,
            mk3Num: 0,
            mk4Num: 0,
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object({
            comments: Yup.string().required(),
            mk1: Yup.string().required(),
            mk2: Yup.string().required(),
            mk3: Yup.string().required(),
            mk4: Yup.string().required(),
            mk1Num: Yup.number().positive().max(5),
            mk2Num: Yup.number().positive().max(5),
            mk3Num: Yup.number().positive().max(5),
            mk4Num: Yup.number().positive().max(5),
          })}
          onSubmit={async (values, { setErrors, setSubmitting }) => {
            try {
              console.log(values);
              const totalGrade =
                values.mk1Num + values.mk2Num + values.mk3Num + values.mk4Num;
              await addToSubmittedAssignment(
                courseId,
                assignmentId,
                values,
                totalGrade
              );
              setSubmitting(false);
            } catch (error) {
              setErrors({ err: error.message });
            }
          }}
        >
          {({ isSubmitting, isValid, dirty, errors, values }) => (
            <Form className='ui form'>
              <TextArea
                name='comments'
                placeholder='Enter Comments Here'
                rows={10}
              />
              <Grid>
                <Grid.Column width={14}>
                  <TextInput name='mk1' placeholder='Enter Marking Key 1' />
                  <TextInput name='mk2' placeholder='Enter Marking Key 2' />
                  <TextInput name='mk3' placeholder='Enter Marking Key 3' />
                  <TextInput name='mk4' placeholder='Enter Marking Key 4' />
                </Grid.Column>
                <Grid.Column width={2}>
                  <TextInput name='mk1Num' type='number' />
                  <TextInput name='mk2Num' type='number' />
                  <TextInput name='mk3Num' type='number' />
                  <TextInput name='mk4Num' type='number' />
                </Grid.Column>
              </Grid>

              {errors.err && (
                <Label
                  basic
                  color='red'
                  style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
                  content={errors.err}
                />
              )}
              <br />
              <Button
                loading={isSubmitting}
                disabled={!isValid || !dirty || isSubmitting}
                type='submit'
                fluidsize='large'
                color='teal'
                content='Submit'
              />
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </Segment>
```

Also, i am using Semantic UI react for styling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the submit method to Form render params:

```
{({ isSubmitting, submitForm, isValid, dirty, errors, values }) => (...
```

And then call it on submit button:

```
<Button
  loading={isSubmitting}
  disabled={!isValid || !dirty || isSubmitting}
  type='submit'
  fluidsize='large'
  color='teal'
  content='Submit'
  onClick={submitForm}
/>
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I had been struggling for so long. But I didnt have this in my other component and it worked fine. Any idea whats happening?

Comment: It could be the yup validation failing silently. Try removing it and see if it'll submit without calling submitForm

Comment: Sure. Let me try thar. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and it turned out to be Yup silent failing a validation check. I simply removed the `.required()` from some of the object's properties to get it to work.

Comment: it help me as well

Comment: Lovely! It was silent, indeed.